# Casting Two Streams Simultaneously

Tags: google-cast

Is it possible to cast two streams from two different URL's simultaneously? How can I achieve that? I guess I would need to add another  tag in the receiver application. How can I control the second video tag in the receiver application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have one video element active at a time on a Chromecast device.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. The Chromecast ecosystem is designed to use a single app at time. Maybe, if you could create another app which accept two streams you could do that, but in the current state you can't.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, you cannot create an app that accepts two streams simultaneously, see Leon Nicholls answer which is the correct one.